# Jboss Hornetq : queue Vs jms-queue

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, messaging, hornetq

In the messaging subsystem of jboss there are two possibilities to create a queue:

hornetq-server=default/queue= and hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=

What is the difference between these two queues?

In which case we should use "queue" instead of jms-queue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HornetQ lets you create [Core queues](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.CR2/docs/user-manual/html/using-core.html) as well as JMS queues. The core queues are suported by its own core api and it is importantly non-JMS api.

So if you use core queues you are tied to HOrnetq and lose the advantages of JMS.

Comment: Thank you I missed this information about "Core queues".